# 9 patch image not stretching

Tags: android, kotlin, nine-patch

I am trying to show this balloon using 9 patch image, though the background imaged doesn't seem to stretch according to the text I defined.

I have set the content area as shown in image 1. And the current output is shown in image 2.

I am welcome for any help. Thanks.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/balloonView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, this is dummy text"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/balloon" />
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBde7.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYphy.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaWZT.png)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaWZT.png)

Comment: Did you add to file name `.9`? It should be like: `image.9.png`

Comment: Yes, I did "balloon.9.png"

Comment: Add your 9-patch image to the post.

Comment: Added in image 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did copy-paste of your `TextView` with 9-patch (added to `res > drawable` as `balloon.9.png`) and it works.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/balloon"
        android:text="Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, this is dummy text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/balloon"
        android:text="Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, this is dummy text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/balloon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="Title this is dummy text, this is dummy text, this is dummy text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is output (from emulator):
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I actually found myself setting the absolute size with LayoutParams when I inflate the view, and that was why. My bad...